# VS Code installing extensions from the command line fails on certificate

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on scripting the setup of our dev machines via chocolately, etc. and I've gotten it to install VS Code, but my attempts to script adding extensions end in failure.

```
ps> cmd /c code --install-extension ms-python.python
```

gives...

```
Installing extensions...    
self signed certificate in certificate chain    
Failed Installing Extensions: ms-python.python
```

I can, however, manage this inside of VSCode without an issue.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

fyi:  yes, I'm in a corporate environment.   I believe we have a proxy server but that's the extent of my knowledge(I'm an ignorant embedded developer, unwise to the ways of the internet)

also fyi:   VSCode was installed via chocolatey, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it doesn't directly answer the question (it appears that the CLI part of vscode does not respect proxy settings), I resolved my specific problem by downloading the .vsix files for the extensions required and put them in my configuration-as-code repo/deliverable.

```
code --install-extension vscode_extensions\cpptools-win32.vsix
```

Seems to work fine.  It's a mild pain in the butt to go and download each one (there's a link available on the market place for the extension marked:  'Download Extension'), but at least I can get them installed and my users can update to the latest version after the fact.

[image]

Comment: I use this strategy as well, and it works so long as the extension being installed does not make subsequent http calls to download additional resources.